# How should I react to an email saying my Apple password has changed?

Tags: ios, icloud, security

Few weeks back I had a email from Apple telling me that my account was being tried to logon to from location they don’t recognise “China”. And they have locked down my account. Today I got email “Your password has successfully Reset” where as I never did changed. It had a link for me to go to “Resolution Centre” if it wasn’t me. I am bit confused on if it’s a phishing email or really from Apple? 
And what does it mean “Password Successfully Reset”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't tell if it's a phishing email or not because you didn't supply any info about it. It's *probably* phishing because it often is.

To be safe, just go to [Apple's ID Reset page](https://appleid.apple.com/) on a device you trust and reset your password. This is especially urgent if you used your AppleID password at another service that was compromised, or it’s easy to guess - one of the 1,000 most common passwords like 123456.

If you're allowed to complete the reset then you know the emails, both of them, were fake.

If you can't do the reset, you'll have to contact Apple Support ASAP. In no circumstances should you click the links directly in the emails since if they're fake, the web sites you click on will harvest your actual password and you will have given up access to your account. If they are real, you will have the best chance to undo the change that was made by following Apple’s recovery from navigating to Apple pages directly:

- https://appleid.apple.com/

Here’s an explanation how to trace a mail and find out if it’s legitimate with images in case that helps:

- [Is this a legitimate email address from Apple support?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360744/is-this-a-legitimate-email-address-from-apple-support)

Comment: I realised maybe those email must be phishing coz I have two step verification enabled.